# Using RV Outlet as Junction Box

Tags: electrical, wiring

If I'm turning a 30amp rv outlet into a junction box that will feed my shed via 10/3 UF going to a BR220 20AMP Double pole breaker enclosure do I need to switch the single pole 30 amp in my main to a double pole 30 amp? Or should I just use half of the BR220?

Comment: What breaker, wire and voltage do you have feeding the  rv outlet?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 10/2 going to the rv outlet and you are not replacing it with 10/3, then leave the single pole breaker. Tap the existing 120V  to the red and black from the new 30/3. You will only have 120 volts on each leg of the new panel and they will be the same phase, no 240V will be available to your shed. If you want 120/240V in the shed, you'll have to have/replace the wire feeding the rv outlet to 10/3. Then replace the single breaker with a double pole breaker in the main panel. Connect that 10/3 to the 10/3 going to the shed.

Comment: Is it allowed to connect two live wires to a single source?  Is that not a parallel(?) circuit.  Just asking for confirmation, I know you can split one wire into two at the other breaker for two 120 sides.

Comment: I have just went ahead and removed the 10/2 and added a  double pole BR230 so I can run 10/3 from panel to panel and no it's not parallel that was the reason behind switching to a double pole if I would have kept the single I would have only been able to run one hot a neutral and ground now I can run both hots

Comment: @crip659  It would not be parallel because the two live wires would be going to two different breakers in the shed.